# If $||f(x)-f(y)||\geqslant 2||x-y||$, then $f$ is surjective.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n $ that has continuous derivative satisfies:
$$(\forall x,y\in{\mathbb{R}^n})\|f(x)-f(y)\|\geqslant 2\|x-y\|,$$ then $f$ is surjective. Can someone help me with solving this problem?

Comment: This question is similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203237/how-to-prove-f-is-onto-if-f-is-continuous-and-satisfying-fx-fy-≥

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to prove, $f$ is onto if $f$ is continuous and satisfying $|f(x) - f(y)| ≥ |x - y|$ for all $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203237/how-to-prove-f-is-onto-if-f-is-continuous-and-satisfying-fx-fy-%e2%89%a5)

Comment: That is only case $n=1$ and can't help for $n>1$

Comment: @bluemath:  Let's use your comment ("can't help for $n \gt 1$") to supply some context for the Question, esp. if you can put that claim in sharper form.

Answer (score 6):

First, notice that $f$ is a proper map, indeed one has:
$$\lim_{\|x\|\to+\infty}\|f(x)\|=+\infty.$$
Therefore, $f$ is a closed map.

Now, notice that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, since $f$ is continuously differentiable, one has:
$$\|\mathrm{d}_xf\cdot h\|=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\|f(x+th)-f(x)\|}{t}\geqslant 2\|h\|.$$
Therefore, $\mathrm{d}_xf$ is injective and thus invertible. Hence, using the inverse function theorem, $f$ is locally invertible everywhere and thus is an open map.

Finally, $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is clopen in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and non-empty. Whence, by connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^n$, one has $f(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Remark.** One can prove that $f$ is actually a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$, this is the [Hadarmard-Lévy theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303332/an-application-of-hadamard-l%C3%A9vys-theorem/). However, in this precise case it is easy to see that $f$ is a diffeomorphism, since $f$ is injective:
$$\|f(x)-f(y)\|=0\Rightarrow \|x-y\|=0.$$

Comment: How do you conclude that $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^n}$ is a closed map?

Comment: @Ibs Since $\|f(x)\|$ tends to $+\infty$ as $\|x\|$ goes to $+\infty$, it is seen that $f$ is a proper map (the inverse image of compact is a compact, indeed it is closed by continuity of $f$ and bounded with the assumption), then $f$ is closed (use that the union of a sequence with its limit is compact).

Comment: Ok.....but I have some other approach to that, Wikipedia says that *A bijective map is open if and only if it is closed* ,if it is so then with help of inverse function theorem we can say that $f$ is an open map ,hence a closed map

Comment: Can you provide me the proof the statement given in Wikipedia i.e  **A bijective map is open if and only if it is closed**